# Adding advanced filter (parameter) options

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

There is a database for recording meter readings in which hour values ​​are added. And contains three parameters:

Day

Hour

Month

```
DT                      Tag                 Value
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elCAS1.P  864499.11758334
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elFF01.P  178171.305
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elFF03.P  179790.971
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elFF04.P  415037.493
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elFF06.P  14591.607421875
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elFF07.P  123602.875
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elFF09.P  18281.70703125
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elL203.P  38017.9453125
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elL204.P  5353.787109375
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elL208.P  78416.609375
2019-09-04 16:00:00.647 ModbusTCP.elL306.P  42133.484375
```

The procedure below works correctly, but I would like to add a few more parameters:

> **- Day Shift (from 07 am to 07 pm)**
>
> **- Night Shift (from 07 pm to 07 am)**

I would appreciate to any help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ElCounters_by_Machines]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@dtStart datetime,
@dtEnd datetime,
@dtPeriod nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(16), DATEADD(mi, CASE
      WHEN DATEPART(mi, [DT]) > 30 THEN 60 - DATEPART(mi, [DT])
      ELSE -DATEPART(mi, [DT])
    END, [DT]), 121) AS DT,
    Tag AS Name,
    Value INTO #Sel
  FROM tblCounters
  WHERE DT BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -20, @dtStart) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 1445, @dtEnd)

  CREATE TABLE #t (
    DT datetime,
    Name nvarchar(150),
    Value float(2)
  )
  IF @dtPeriod = 'Day'

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #t
      SELECT
        DT,
        Name,
        Value
      FROM #Sel
      WHERE CAST(DT AS time) = '00:00'
  END

  ELSE
  IF @dtPeriod = 'Hour'

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #t
      SELECT
        DT,
        Name,
        Value
      FROM #Sel
  END

  ELSE
  IF @dtPeriod = 'Month'

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #t
      SELECT
        DT,
        Name,
        Value
      FROM #Sel
      WHERE DATEPART(DAY, DT) = '1'
      AND CAST(DT AS time) = '00:00'
  END

  DROP TABLE #Sel

  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT) AS Rw,
    DT,
    Value AS FF01 INTO #t01
  FROM #t
  WHERE Name LIKE '%elFF01.P'

  SELECT
    DT,
    Value AS FF03 INTO #t02
  FROM #t
  WHERE Name LIKE '%elFF03.P'

  SELECT
    DT,
    Value AS FF04 INTO #t03
  FROM #t
  WHERE Name LIKE '%elFF04.P'

  SELECT
    DT,
    Value AS FF06 INTO #t04
  FROM #t
  WHERE Name LIKE '%elFF06.P'

  SELECT
    DT,
    Value AS FF07 INTO #t05
  FROM #t
  WHERE Name LIKE '%elFF07.P'

  SELECT
    DT,
    Value AS FF09 INTO #t06
  FROM #t
  WHERE Name LIKE '%elFF09.P'

  SELECT
    _01.Rw, _01.DT, FF01, FF03, FF04, FF06, FF07, FF09 INTO #t100
  FROM #t01 _01

  LEFT JOIN #t02 _02  ON _01.DT = _02.DT
  LEFT JOIN #t03 _03  ON _01.DT = _03.DT
  LEFT JOIN #t04 _04  ON _01.DT = _04.DT
  LEFT JOIN #t05 _05  ON _01.DT = _05.DT
  LEFT JOIN #t06 _06  ON _01.DT = _06.DT
  
  SELECT
    * INTO #t200
  FROM #t100
  SELECT 
    _100.DT,
    ROUND((_200.FF01 - _100.FF01), 0) AS FF01,
    ROUND((_200.FF03 - _100.FF03), 0) AS FF03,
    ROUND((_200.FF04 - _100.FF04), 0) AS FF04,
    ROUND((_200.FF06 - _100.FF06), 0) AS FF06,
    ROUND((_200.FF07 - _100.FF07), 0) AS FF07,
    ROUND((_200.FF09 - _100.FF09), 0) AS FF09 INTO #t300 
  FROM #t100 _100
  JOIN #t200 _200
    ON _200.Rw = _100.Rw + 1
  ORDER BY DT
  SELECT
    *
  FROM #t300
  ORDER BY DT

  DROP TABLE #t, #t01, #t02, #t03, #t04, #t05, #t06, #t100, #t200, #t300

END
GO
```

**Another form of report in which there is a similar filter:**

```
cross apply (
    select
       datediff(hour,'20180101 07:00', dt) % 24 hr) ca1
cross apply (
    select 
      case
          when  ca1.hr between 0  and 11 then 'D'
          when  ca1.hr between 12 and 23 then 'N'
          end as shift, 
          convert(varchar(13),dateadd(hour,-(case when hr < 12 then hr else hr-12 end),dt),121) shift_start) ca2
;

if @dtPeriod = 'Day' 
begin 
 insert into #t600 select * from #t500 where shift = 'D'
end

if @dtPeriod = 'Night'
begin 
  insert into #t600 select * from #t500 where shift = 'N'
end
```

I would like to see the following selection of parameters when generating the report:

> **1. Day Shift**
>
> **2. Night Shift**
>
> **3. Hour**
>
> **4. Day**
>
> **5. Month**

**Expected result:**

> Combining two separate (used in different reports) parameters into one or the correct query written from scratch to display values ​​for the selected parameter

**Below are the available reporting forms with "DAY, MONTH, HOUR" parameters:**

[If selected "DAY" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCdxA.jpg)

[If selected "MONTH" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFcmW.jpg)

[If selected "HOUR" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxSRN.jpg)

**Below are the available reporting forms with "ALL, DAY, NIGHT" parameters:**

[If selected "ALL" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhBNf.jpg)

[If selected "DAY" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8Z5.jpg)

[If selected "NIGHT" parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM0c2.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Is your issue "how to add Day shift and night shift parameters to the report" or how to construct the query? What are the expected values and data types for these parameters? Sounds like you only need one additional parameter called `shift` that has the values 'D' and 'N' but it's pretty hard to piece together... Also if Hour Day Month can select a single hour range, then what are the Day and Night parameters supposed to do? A minimal dataset to run this locally would help a lot.

Comment: Wow that is some seriously cryptic code. I followed it for awhile but then it just melts my brain.